# Another Maximum Execution Time Fatal Error

Tags: php

I'm using phpDesigner8 and have a dead simple PHP script:

```
<?php
/*
Trying to debug error
*/
echo 'this is a test';
?>
```

When I "Run" it, it works perfectly. If I run it from a command line, it works perfectly. However when I "Debug" it, I immediately get the dreaded:

Fatal Error
Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded.

I have read other posts and have set max_execution_time = 300 and max_input_time = 5000 in php.ini.

Help?

Comment: Have you set it in the *correct* php.ini?

Comment: I thought so- the php.ini located in ...\phpdesigner8\php

Answer (score 0):

Check which configuration your debug uses and set it correctly there. I have no idea what editor that is as I have never seen it before, but it should be debuggable.

Comment: phpDesigner uses XDebuger as its default debugging tool.

Comment: The debugger obviously uses a different configuration file than what your other scripts use. Find that file and you have the source of your problem.